# Standard Deviation from Proportion

Tags: standard-deviation, sample-size, proportion, sample

I have to find the standard deviation when I only have population proportion percentage (8%) and sample size (50). Can you help me out how could I calculate and get to the standard deviation of the sample?

EDIT: The original question is (value name changed):
Assume that 8% of all fish have green scales. In a random sample of 50 fish, what is the standard deviation of the proportion of fish in the sample that have green scales?

Comment: So far you have asked two questions that are answered in a great number of posts on this site.  If you have additional ones of the same nature, then please consider searching for answers before posting the questions.

Comment: Thank you, will search more before posting again. Apologies for posting answered questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ be a Bernoulli random variable with probability of success $p=0.08$.

Then the mean of $X$ is $$E(X)=\sum_{x} x \Pr \left({X = x}\right)=1*p+0*(1-p)=p$$
The variance of $X$ is 
$$E(X^2)-[E(X)]^2=\sum_{x} x^2 \Pr \left({X = x}\right)-p^2=p-p^2=p(1-p)$$

Suppose $X_1,...,X_{50}$ is a random sample from the distribution of $X$

What you need to find is the standard deviation (or standard error) of $\bar{X}$

Comment: Why do you invoke the CLT?  It's irrelevant (and not even applicable).  The variance is the variance of a mean of independent Bernoulli variables, period.

Comment: @whuer, yes, no need to invoke the CLT, I will modify the response

Comment: @Xi'an, I will modify the response